# Angular 2 background image not rendering

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 app that has a single component currently.
For the entire page, I want to render a background image on the page. I have done the following:
`app.component.html`

```
<dashboard class="dash"></dashboard>
```

`app.component.css`

```
.dash {
    background-image: url("../assets/images/background/sligo.jpg");
}
```

in the dev tools in chrome, the image is showing up, but on the actual view, it still shows a blank screen. What am I missing?
The below snip shows the console output and the main view.

[image]

Additional info; here's a snip of my package.json and the folder structure[image]

[image]

Comment: URL path is fine. You can click the link in the styles box and open the image with the provided url

Comment: Does the networking tool show all files loading correctly?

Comment: Yes, I get a compilation error if the URL isn't resolved, but there are no http requests for the file

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify `assets` and `root` properties correctly in your `.angular-cli.json`, for example:

[image]

And the structure of my project:

[image]

And you should use `content` instead of `background-image`, like this:

```
.dash {
    content: url(../assets/images/background/sligo.jpg);
}
```

Comment: @mcgowan.b, I don't see, `assets` folder is inside `src`? There are no parent folders between them?

Comment: @mcgowan.b, I have updated the answer with one more try to help, it's at the bottom (about `content`), try this one.

Comment: this overlays the image over the entire page, so I only see the image

Comment: @mcgowan.b, you need to add some magic via CSS, I'm using `content` method in my projects, and it's only the way it works. Try to add another one `div` and set `content` property to it (and other needed styles too).